# Adding users to Team Foundation Server from different domain (LDAP)

Tags: tfs, ldap, tfs-2015

I set up a TFS (Team Foundation Server 2015) on a Machine using only local users, but now want to authenticate/add users on the TFS using our corporate AD logins.

We are not allowed to put the TFS into the AD domain itself, as our policy forbids us to do so, the server is not administered by our CIT administrators. On the other hand, we are allowed to use LDAP to authenticate, but I have no idea how or where to configure this.

How can we configure our TFS to authenticate users using an LDAP?

Answer (score 0):

TFS has to be installed in a domain if you want to authenticate domain users.

Answer (score 0):

Managing Team Foundation Server in a workgroup environment is possible but can present some challenges. **Active Directory** environments are recommended for most Team Foundation Server deployments. If Team Foundation Server is to be deployed in a workgroup, it should only be deployed in workgroups with a ***very limited*** number of users and computers. In your case AD is required in TFS setup. In TFS setup as well as configuration, we need a few account, like TFS service account, build account, reporting account.

When connect to TFS from client computers, we need AD user account to authenticate, only domain user can connect to TFS. What you are looking for is not supported and can't be achieved for now.